# How to dynamically add buttons to ListBox - WFP - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, dynamic, listbox

I want to dynamically add buttons to dynamically added ListBox through button at the end of ListBox.

I want ListBox with buttons, which every button will be with different index. Cause after that  I have to put events to that buttons. So buttons will be with index.

Under created ListBox will be button, that after click can add new ListBox with button (the same as first example).

How can I do that?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: Yea, I tried something, but nothing worked..

Comment: @user2740185 please paste some of your code

Comment: Look at my edit. I think that this is solution. :)

Comment: @Martin Gabriel You shoud post your answer separately and accept it as an answer )

Comment: Ok, tomorow I will. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
private Boolean addNewListBox(ListBox targetElement, int indexOfElement)
    {
        ListBox elementListBox = new ListBox();

        elementListBox.Name = "elementListBox" + indexOfElement;
        elementListBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

        targetElement.Items.Remove(addFloor);
        targetElement.Items.Add(elementListBox);
        elementListBox.Items.Add(putElements("TEST", index));
        targetElement.Items.Add(addFloor);
        return true;
    }
public object putElements(string nameOfElement, int indexOfElement)
    {
        if (nameOfElement.Contains("TEST"))
        {
            Button floorButton = new Button();

            floorButton.Name = "floorButton" + indexOfElement;
            floorButton.Content = "floorButton" + indexOfElement;
            floorButton.Height = 60;
            floorButton.Width = 87;
            floorButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 2, 0, 0);

            return floorButton;
        }
    }
```

Of course with event on button. ;)